# Uncleared StateListDrawable behavior on Android

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have very strange phenomenon when I try to use `StateListDrawable`:

I have a view that extends `ImageView`, where I use `StateListDrawable` in its constructor.
I have 2 code snippets, to present my problem. 
The first one:

```
public class MyView extends ImageView{  
Resources r = getResources();
Drawable filteredDrawable = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.smallsale);                    
filteredDrawable.setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(Color.RED, 1));                                     
setImageDrawable(filteredDrawable); 
}
```

And the second one:

```
public class MyView extends ImageView{
Resources r = getResources();
Drawable filteredDrawable = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.smallsale);

filteredDrawable.setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(Color.RED, 1));

StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},  filteredDrawable);
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused}, filteredDrawable);
states.addState(new int[] {}, r.getDrawable(R.drawable.smallsale));

//Notice I do not use 'states' at all...
setImageDrawable(filteredDrawable);
```

}

(I know this code does not make a lot of sense - I wanted to simplify the problem to make the question clearer). The problem is that on the first sinppet everything works fine - I set a color filter on the drawable and it is shown. But on the second snippet, the `StateListDrawable` instance effects somehow on the filter, and the **original** drawable is being shown, even though I never connected it to the `ImageView` by calling `setImageDrawable(states)`.

Can some one explain to me what is going on?
My goal is to use the `StateListDrawable` with the same drawable for different states as follow:

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},  filteredDrawable);
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused}, filteredDrawable);
states.addState(new int[] {}, r.getDrawable(R.drawable.smallsale));
setImageDrawable(states);
```

(I need to do it by code because my drawable should be loaded dynamically from the net, and not as a resource)

Answer (score 3):

Ok.
I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018602/statelistdrawable-to-switch-colorfilters/10571706#10571706)

It turns out that `StateListDrawables`  looses the filter for some reason...
I took SnoK's solution and it works great for me.

I dont know why Google does not feel it should be noted on the docs as a side effect...