# How to remove the Default orange Highlight Effect for EditText programmatically?

Tags: android, android-edittext, state, highlighting

I use selector for styling EditTexts. I want to get rid of orange color, when I doubleTap on my EditText. I use this:

```
states.addState(new int[] {R.attr.textColorHighlight}, getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent));
```

But it doesn't make any difference! Does any body know why?
and interestingly this part of the code works well:

```
states.addState(new int[] {R.attr.state_focused}, getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent));
```

But I don't want to change the state, when focuced!

Comment: I think the color is dependent on your OEM rom.

Comment: u mean there is no way to change it programmatically?

Comment: create your custom style for your EditText and make it looks like as you want.

Comment: @Android-Developer: But I thought I've done that with states.addState ...

Comment: you wan't to change the color when your activity shows up? is that what you want and don't change it's state when user select it?

Comment: I want to remove the orange color wenn I highlight the text in edittext, or what do you mean?

Comment: What orange color are you referring to? If it's the orange color around the text boxes, a) that's android 2.3, and it's part of the text view drawables b) I believe `R.attr.textColorHighlight` is the color for the *selection*.

Comment: It is Android 2.3. I'm talking about the text in EditText and when I highlight the text, the backgroundColor of the text goes orange, not the edittext itself actually.  :-(

Comment: He's talking about the highlight color when you're selecting text like when you long click on text in the browser and move the handles. Same as the one in the edittext.

Answer (score 1):

This is not that easy (programmatically). You could try to achieve this by using [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html). You can use a StateListDrawable as the background of your EditText in your theme so you can handle the different states.

If found a very interesting sample which maybe helps you out. Sorry but I didn't try it myself: [Apply StateListDrawable programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018602/statelistdrawable-to-switch-colorfilters/10571706#10571706)